# How to query Firebase Firestore(Not real time database) collection and retrieve data in excel or CSV format

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have developed a web app using flutter and stored the user data in the Firebase cloud Firestore.
I want to retrieve the collection data after querying in JSON or CSV format. Is there any tool or some google service to do so, want to be in my Firebase free quota limit.[image]

Comment: One solution would be to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest). You will be constrained by the JSON format returned by the REST API. Another solution would be to use an HTTP Cloud Function in which you construct the desired JSON and return it to the caller.

Comment: I have seen an extension named BigQuery will it be helpful to query and get data, And if yes then any idea about costing or free quota I will hardly query my collection once a month. @RenaudTarnec